# using multithreaded maven build with flexmojos

Tags: apache-flex, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, flexmojos

I am trying to improve the performance of a multi module maven build by making it multithreaded. While doing that, I am trying to resolve bunch of dependencies and there is something I am stuck at which is an error with the flexmojos-maven-plugin.

Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.9:compile-swf and it simply says (error compiling).

I looked online and it looks like flexmojos does not yet support multithreaded builds and I was wondering if there are any ideas to have a workaround. The build I am working with is huge so we need to make it multithreaded so I am basically looking for a workaround for the moment at least.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a 400+ multi module build running out of Jenkins.
With sequential build it took over an hour. With parallel build, this reduced to much smaller, depending on what modules needed to be built. Some builds were as small a 5 minutes.

The biggest component that always ran was the assembly plugin, which had to package all the modules into a single distributable package.

In this way, you can re-build only the relevant modules.

The trick to getting this to work is that you need to always build to the install phase.
Then you need only build the changed modules, and any modules that depend on them, and the assembly.

Comment: I am trying to do this in stages and since I've already spent sometime working on making it multithreaded it would be a waste of time to start a fully new approach right now but I am considering a continuos effort to make the build more efficient. For now, I need to solve this issue in order to get closer to making the build multithreaded. Thanks for the comment!